# How to make the scrollbar of a QListView report its correct value after a model update?

Tags: qt, scrollbar, qlistview

I'm trying to set the value of a QListView scrollbar immediately after updating its model. The problem is that the scrollbar is not properly setup at that time so its `maximum` value is not correct. It means that when I set the value, it will never go above this (incorrect) maximum. If I add some `qDebug` statements in other places, I can see that the maximum is correct again after some time.

I suppose that I need to somehow force an update of the scrollbar or the view but I tried various things - `updateGeometry`, `repaint`, `update`, `setFlow`, etc. without any success.

Any suggestion on what I could do? Below is my current code:

```
int previousScrollValue = cardList_->verticalScrollBar()->value();

qDebug() << "Before" << previousScrollValue;

CardListModel* model = new CardListModel(deck->id());
cardList_->setModel(model); 
cardList_->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(previousScrollValue);

qDebug() << "After" << cardList_->verticalScrollBar()->value(); // Wrong value
qDebug() << "Max" << cardList_->verticalScrollBar()->maximum(); // Wrong value
```

Comment: you have to set the maximum prior to setting any value...

Comment: @UmNyobe, the maximum is automatically set by the QListView. My problem is that it's not set immediately after I change the model.

Comment: Could you tell the finality of setting the scrollbar value, please. There might be a better solution to meet your goal.

Comment: @Koying, when I change the model, the scrollbar goes back to the top, while I need it to stay where it is (the model might be updated while the user is looking at the view).

Comment: You mean that your list goes to the top, while you want it to stay at the bottom, right?

Comment: @Koying, for example if it's down 5 rows of items, I want it to be back to five rows of items after reloading the model. It's because often there's just one item that has been removed or added so it makes sense to restore the scrollbar to where it previously was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of trial and error, I've finally found out what was causing this issue:

I had the QListView layout mode set to `Batched` with a size of 2x2. I'm not sure why I had this set, but I guess it's meant to make the display smoother by rendering batches of items instead of everything in one go. The problem (I guess) is that it messes up with the scrollbar, which continuously gets updated as batches are being rendered, and it only gets in a stable state (with a proper maximum and value) when everything is rendered. Only then does it make sense to call `setValue` on it (but there's no way to know when all the items have been rendered).

So, the fix was simple - I just set back the `layoutMode` to `SinglePass` and now the scrollbar works as expected (and the display is not noticeably slower). No need to save and restore the scrollbar value either, it works as is.

Comment: I just got the same problem. But my layoutMode is always SignlePass. I still can't change the range of my scrollbar. Any solution, plz?

Comment: @MikeShaw, I'd suggest you post a new question, as it's hard to help without seeing any code.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to put a `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` after the `setModel`? I.e.:

```
CardListModel* model = new CardListModel(deck->id());
cardList_->setModel(model); 
QCoreApplication::processEvents();
cardList_->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(previousScrollValue);

qDebug() << "After" << cardList_->verticalScrollBar()->value(); // Wrong value
qDebug() << "Max" << cardList_->verticalScrollBar()->maximum(); // Wrong value
```

I suspect updating the scrollbar values only happen in the event loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [`updateGeometries`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#updateGeometries) is the function you need to call. If you check the implementation of the `scrollToBottom` function you will see that this is the function that is called:

```
void QAbstractItemView::scrollToBottom()
{
    Q_D(QAbstractItemView);
    if (d->delayedPendingLayout) {
        d->executePostedLayout();
        updateGeometries();
    }
    verticalScrollBar()->setValue(verticalScrollBar()->maximum());
}
```

The difference with the `updateGeometry` is that the geometries of the child widgets of the view will be updated.

If that doesn't work you could do:

```
cardList_->scrollToBottom();
qDebug() << "Max" << cardList_->verticalScrollBar()->maximum();
```

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look at `updateGeometries` and `scrollToBottom`.